# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize file types in directory named "templates"

Tags: visual-studio-code, gatsby

I'm working on a Gatsby project with **Microsoft Visual Studio Code** as the code editor.

The project structure is as shown below:

```
.vscode
node_modules
public
src
  - components
  - pages
  - templates
    - blog.js
    - blog.module.scss
.gitignore
package.json

// ...
```

For all the files inside the "template" `[src/templates]` directory, VSCode doesn't recognize the file types & are being set to "Plain Text" by default.

**Solutions tried with no success:**

- Added file associations in `.vscode/setting.json`.
- Disabled all the extensions to see if any extension is causing the issue.

**Details**

> VSCode Version: 1.44.2
>
> OS: Microsoft Windows 10

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an extension which was used for **Emmet Abbreviations in Django HTML Templates**. The extension changed the file associations for all the files inside the `Templates` folder to Django HTML and hence, all other files were being detected as plain text.

Clearing out the Django HTML file association from `settings.json` fixed the issue.